# How to call activiti (subprocess) of another project (within one ear)?

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I'm creating a new project which will be deployed within the same JBOSS server. There is already a project available in the server. I have a functional requirement to call a process residing in another project, basically, it is in another folder.

camunda provides an attribute "calledTenantId" which allows calling a process of another tenant within the project

```
<callActivity id="callActivity1" name="Check credit" 
   calledElement="testProcess" />
```

I expect a way to call a process of in another project (deployed folder)

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by 'call a process', do you want to start a new process?

Comment: Yes I want to start a new process.

Comment: Then, any reason you cannot use a signal or a message start event to start the process?

Comment: No specific reason. But will it work across project? Can a signal message trigger process in other projects.

Comment: The short answer is yes